# The boy and the bird

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, story

> Once there was a tree, and a bird landed on it and started pulling the leaves off. Eventually a boy came along and ate the bird, and the tree grew back its leaves.

**What happened?**

Hint:

> This happens on a regular basis

Comment: Nice riddle! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might it be

> 'The changing of seasons'
>  in which the bird would be autumn or abscission (The process in which a tree loses its leaves). The boy would then be the change to a next season (getting rid of the bird). In which the tree starts to get his leaves back. And of course the changing of seasons occurs on a regular basis

Comment: Yes! Well done on getting the answer

Comment: @RohitJose Nice riddle had me wondering for some time, until this morning I had a discussion with a friend of mine between summer and winter hours and then it struck me :p.

Answer (score 10):

No laughing, but:

> The boy's name was Robin. So:
>
>  Robin ate the robin who was robbin' pieces of the [Picea Rubens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picea_rubens), and the Picea Rubens re-budded.

Comment: What... I have no idea what you said but thank you for taking the effort of saying it!

Answer (score 6):

*Answered before the hint was included.*

---

This mimics the story of

> **The Selfish Giant** by *Oscar Wilde* (one of my favourite tales!). 
>  <sub>**WARNING**: SPOILER ALERTS WILL FOLLOW.</sub>

`Once there was a tree,`

> The **Giant's beautiful garden**.

`and a bird landed on it`

> The Giant surrounds his garden with a high wall and a **notice-board** (the **bird**; "bird" sounds like "board") reading TRESPASSERS WILL BE PROSECUTED.

`and started pulling the leaves off`

> There suddenly came an **eternal winter** in the Giant's garden for which all the leaves **fell off** and the trees bore no golden fruit.

`Eventually a boy came along`

> The **Giant**.

`and ate the bird`

> The Giant took a great **axe** ("axe" sounds like "ate") and cut down the high wall.

`and the tree grew back its leaves.`

> The Giant puts a crying boy up into a tree, wherefore it **blossoms** and the Garden stays beautiful again, forever and ever.

---

Both stories are split into three parts:

1. > The tree with the bird. (**Expulsion from the Garden**)

2. > The bird pulling off the leaves. (**Dances of Eternal Winter**)

3. > The leaves grew back and the bird is gone. (**The Return of Spring**)

Comment: I read that story! It's very nice and an interesting interpretation of my riddle, but again, not the correct answer.

Comment: @RohitJose I thought I had it for a sec... eh, oh well. I need to go to bed. I want to see if by, say, tomorrow morning, someone has answered it correctly; I really want to know what the answer is :D

Comment: Well, if anything were to solve a riddle, it would be stack exchange puzzling, right?

Comment: @RohitJose and there you 'ave it, folks! It's our new motto! :P

Answer (score 3):

> Time elapsed. 
> Time will heal each and every thing happened to you, no matter how horrible it may be.

Comment: That's very poetic of you, but not the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Answer 1.

> The boy ate the bird which had the leaves in it so now the boy as the leaves in him because he ate the bird. When he died, he became decayed into the ground and into the soil. So the leaves in the boy are now in the soil which helps the tree grow back the leaves.

Answer 2

> The boy threw away the part of the bird which had the leaves in it and now that part gets decayed in the soil. So the soil now has the leaves which helps the tree grow back it's leaves.

Comment: That's a good was of looking at it, but incorrect.